# Select 2 Label is not changed using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="Country" id="Country" class="select2" ng-change="viewState()">
    <option value=''>Select Country</option>
    <option ng-repeat="Country in AllCountry"
            ng-value="[[Country.CountryID]]"
            value="[[Country.CountryID]]">[[Country.CountryName]]
    </option>
</select>
```

**Angulajs**

```
$scope.Country=23;
```

**Problem**

When I run this code the value is selected but the label is not changed, I attached the screen shot.

[image]

Comment: jquery-select2 does not bind to the AngularJS framework without custom directives. Consider using a third-party library like [AngularJS-native version of Select2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select)

Answer (score 1):

The issue occurs when angularjs compares your `Country` value with `value` attribute inside `<option>` i-e `<option value="Country.CountryID">`. `Country` is number, while option's values are in `string`. In short, the issue is with the type mismatch.

The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) says that

> When the model needs to be bound to a non-string value, you must
>   either explictly convert it using a directive (see example below) or
>   use ngOptions to specify the set of options. This is because an option
>   element can only be bound to string values at present.

So you can use `ngOptions` to solve the issue, as you can see in the code snippet attached.

```html
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect"
  ng-options="option.CountryID as option.CountryName for option in AllCountry" ng-model="Country">
</select>
```

Comment: I tried but its not working. (its works perfectly on normal select, its not working on select2)

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-option instead of option with ng-repeat ...

```
<select ng-model="Country" id="Country" class="select2" ng-change="viewState()">
    <option value=''>Select Country</option>
    <option ng-repeat="Country in AllCountry"
            ng-value="Country.CountryID"
            value="{{Country.CountryID}}">{{Country.CountryName}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Please use angular{{}} instead of [[]] for binding....Hope it will work for you

```
$scope.Country=22;
    $scope.AllCountry = {
    "India": {
        "CountryName":"India",
        "CountryID": 1
    },
    "USA": {
        "CountryName":"USA",
        "CountryID": 22
    },
    "USR": {
    "CountryName":"USR",
        "CountryID": 2
    }
```

Comment: Iam using laravel + angularjs thats why I use [[]]

Comment: Ok,Laravel is a framework  But wherever you substitute angular values in view it must be inside angular braces.

Comment: We can use custom interpolateProvider in angular js

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<ui-select ng-model="CountryScope.selected" theme="bootstrap">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a person in the list...">[[$select.selected.CountryName]]</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices  repeat="Country in (AllCountry | filter: $select.search) track by Country.CountryID">
       <div ng-bind-html="Country.CountryName | highlight: $select.search"></div>
       <small ng-bind-html="Country.CountryName | highlight: $select.search"></small>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

**AngularJS**

```
$scope.AllCountry=[
        {  CountryID: 1, CountryName: 'United States' },
        {  CountryID: 2,  CountryName: 'Argentina' },
        {  CountryID: 3,   CountryName: 'Argentina' }
      ];
```

*To Set Value*

```
$scope.CountryScope.selected= { CountryID: 2,  CountryName: 'Argentina' };
```

*To Get Value*

```
$scope.CountryScope.selected.CountryID
```

Click here for [**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/G839YR)

Click for [**Reference**](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/#examples)